# Tensorflow Square function recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to learn the basics of machine learning. I am trying to train the AI the square function: 2^x

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = np.array([2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0], dtype=int)
ys = np.array([4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 32.0, 64.0, 128.0, 256.0, 512.0, 1024.0, 2048.0, 4096.0, 8192.0, 16384.0, 32768.0], dtype=int)

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1000)

print(model.predict([7.0]))
```

This should print +- 128 but the outcome is in the 2000th's and the loss is extremely high.

How can I optimize this neural network so it gives me more accurate answer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: please read the below link : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/10/tutorial-optimizing-neural-networks-using-keras-with-image-recognition-case-study/

Answer (score 0):

When you are training a **Neural Network**, which seems to be easy for you might be hard for the Computer. In your case training **2 raised to nth power**; training this pattern is somewhat hard to be discovered as the values changes **drastically**, this may or may not result in **converging** to a specific value.

As for the question on how to **optimize a neural network** to create a more accurate model some of the ways to achieve this is to **add more layers**, **fine-tune hyper-parameters**,  making **more complex models**, and even **creating your own layer, operations, functions**.

If you are trying to learn the Basics of Machine Learning, there are many guides available to get you up the **basics** in TensorFlow Documentation.

Try to follow the curriculum in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/learn-ml/basics-of-machine-learning) for a more clear path to study.